# I want to convert a label numpy array into binary matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have numpy array:

```
a = [355, 355, 1005, 7005, 7005, 7005]
```

I like this to be converted into binary matrix without any loop (if possible using a single line of code) like this:

```
m = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear, do you want some kind of one-hot encoding?

```
a = np.array([355, 355, 1005, 7005, 7005, 7005])

m = (a==np.unique(a,)[:,None]).astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: I don't know whether the output of an unordered input array meets the requirements of OP, maybe it needs to `return_index`.

Comment: @MechanicPig I don't know the exact logic (thus my question), but yes, the order can be rearranged depending on the use case